# Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap, if yes how do I get the overlapped time with new start and end time

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime

I am using jquery full calendar to show events. It's working fine, but I have a scenario where I have to show the availability of person by subtracting his busy time.

So I have two type of events with start and end date
1. person busy time events
2. person available time events

Example : if a person is available 9am-5pm, but he is busy 11am-3pm. Now overlap is occurring from 11am-3pm, now I would like to split it should return me two new events by minus his busy time from the available time. It would return me two new events one from 9am-11am and second one from 3pm-5pm. How do I get this

```
public bool Intersects(DateTime r1start, DateTime r1end, DateTime r2start, DateTime r2end)
    {
        return (r1start == r2start) || (r1start > r2start ? r1start <= r2end : r2start <= r1end);
    }
```

Now as I'm able to get overlap if happening, but now I would like to split that overlap and create new events with start and end time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this implementation of the DateRange :

```
public class DateRange : IEquatable<DateRange>
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public DateRange Intersect(DateRange d)
    {
        var s = (d.Start > this.Start) ? d.Start : this.Start; // Later Start
        var e = (d.End < this.End) ? d.End : this.End; // Earlier ending

        if (s < e)
            return new DateRange() { Start = s, End = e };
        else
            return null;
    }

    public bool Contains(DateTime d)
    {
        return d >= Start && d <= End;
    }

    public bool Equals(DateRange obj)
    {
        return Start.Equals(obj.Start) && End.Equals(obj.End);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var d1 =new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
var d2 =new DateRange() { Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), End = DateTime.Now };

Console.WriteLine(d1.Intersect(d2));
```

**EDIT2**

```
    public List<DateRange> Intersect2(DateRange d)
    {
        var s = (d.Start > this.Start) ? d.Start : this.Start; // Later Start
        var e = (d.End < this.End) ? d.End : this.End; // Earlier ending

        if (s < e)
            return new List<DateRange>()
            {
                new DateRange() { Start = new DateTime(Math.Min(Start.Ticks, d.Start.Ticks)), End = s },
                new DateRange() { Start = e, End = new DateTime(Math.Max(End.Ticks, d.End.Ticks)) }
            };
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I'm having two date ranges not one. In the above example

Comment: Thanks it returning the overlapping start and end time that's awesome, but one last thing if you will help me out. I actually need the start and end time not overlapping periods. if there is overlap in middle then it should return two events start and end time. One before overlap and one after overlap.

Comment: You can change the return with something like this :
                `return new List<DateRange>()
                {
                    new DateRange() { Start = new DateTime(Math.Min(Start.Ticks, d.Start.Ticks)), End = s },
                    new DateRange() { Start = e, End = new DateTime(Math.Min(End.Ticks, d.End.Ticks)) }
                };`

Comment: HI thanks almost there, but one thing it's returning start and end before the overlap but after the overlap portion is returning wrong values. Example :- if available is 9am-5pm and overlapping is 11am-3pm. It's returning first portion values correct like 9am-11am, but after overlap end like 3pm-5pm isn't getting still. may be minor thing you missed.

Comment: Oh sorry its because its Max not min

Comment: Could you please update the code, so I can give a shot.

Comment: Thanks a Ton, I can't up vote as not have privileges,  just updated code:  return new List<DateRange>()
            {
                new DateRange() { Start = new DateTime(Math.Min(Start.Ticks, d.Start.Ticks)), End = s },
                new DateRange() { Start = e, End = new DateTime(Math.Max(End.Ticks, d.End.Ticks)) }
            };

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to SO. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done Bro, keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

In your last statement you have a mistake: present r2start == r1end in all cases.
Maybe:

1. r1start < r2end : r2start <**=** r1end
2. r1start <**=** r2end : r2start < r1end
   ?

I solve this problem that condition:

```
return r1Start <= r2Start && r1End >= r2Start ||
        r1Start <= r2Start && r1End >= r2End ||
        r1Start >= r2Start && r1Start < r2Start && r1End <= r2End ||
        r1Start >= r2Start && r1Start <= r2End && r1End <= r2End ||
        r1Start <= r2Start && r1End > r2Start ||
        r1Start >= r2Start && r1Start <= r2End && r1End > r2End;
```

Comment: That logic is fine, I have OR condition not AND. It will work. My main concern is when I get overlap is happening then how do I get the overlap time start and end time.

Comment: This condition do cover all cases of intersect 2 periods.
This solve uses in production code, writed by me.

Answer (score 0):

This will return Free Time

```
public class DateSpan
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public bool Contains(DateSpan ds)
    {
        return ds.Start >= Start && ds.End <= End ;
    }
    public bool IsHitTo( DateTime i)
    {
        return i>= Start && i<= End ;
    }
    public List<DateSpan> GetFreeTime( DateSpan i)
    {
        List<DateSpan> ld = new  List<DateSpan> ();
        if( IsHitTo( i.Start))
        {
            ld.Add(new DateSpan(){ Start = this.Start, End = I.End});
            if( IsHitTo( i.End))
            {
                 ld.Add(new DateSpan(){ Start = i.Start, End = i.Start});
            }
        }
        else
        {
             if( IsHitTo( i.Start))
            {
                 ld.Add(new DateSpan(){ Start = i.End, End = this.End});
            }
            else
            {
                 if(i.Contains(this))
                {
                     return new  List<DateSpan> ();
                }
                else
                {
                     ld.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }
        return ld;
   }
}
```

And use like this

```
List<DateSpan> l =  FreeTime.GetFreeTime(BusyTime);
```

Comment: FreeTime.GetFreeTime(BusyTime) didnt' get the FreeTime what does it ?represents?

Comment: I will **List of DateSpan** ,each `DateSpan` has `Start` and `End` .I wrote it with mobile and I didn't test it .so  I will test it and if it have any errors I will edit my answer.I think it will return correct .